# Importing spaCy object (nlp) into a different Docker container running Django project

Tags: python, django, docker, spacy

I am running a docker-compose file with 3 services (or containers):

- django-web
- nginx
- spacy-web

My final goal is to create 2 nlp objects (nlp_en, nlp_fr) in spacy-web and make use of them in django-web. 
Does that look possible/desirable? 
Of course, the reason behind splitting django-web and spacy-web is to have a cleaner scheme of containers.

I have created a Dockerfile for spacy-web. 
I install spaCy and 2 language models (English/French). 
With an entrypoint (which runs a python script: spacy_entrypoint.py), I then create 2 nlp objects, 1 for each language (nlp_en, nlp_fr).

My first problem is that this container exits immediately after creating the nlp objects. My guess is that I should add something at the end of the python script, to keep the container running, but without using much CPU. How do we keep a python container alive, to access objects created into it from another container?

If that problem can be solved, then I need to import the nlp objects (nlp_en, nlp_fr) in the other container, namely django-web. I never got there because spacy-web exits immediately after creation. In the relevant django views, I would try "from spacy-web import nlp_en, nlp_fr". Has anyone tried an python import from one Docker container to another Docker container?

## Dockerfile.spacy

```
FROM python:3.7.4
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -U spacy
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
RUN python3 -m spacy download fr_core_news_md
ENV updated_at 2019-09-06
EXPOSE 4000
RUN mkdir -p /temp
WORKDIR /temp
COPY compose_spacy/spacy_entrypoint.py /temp
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "spacy_entrypoint.py"]
```

## spacy_entrypoint.py

```
import spacy
nlp_en = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
nlp_fr = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')
```

When I build an image and run a container based on those files, the container exits immediately. I'd be extremely grateful for any tip pointing to the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting simple and just having everything in one application and one container.